# Angular 17 Server Side Rendering data loading logic

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I am updating my angular app website to work with SSR. Assume I have a "Restaurant Detail" page in my app. I have a `restaurant` property and a `getRestaurant()` function in .ts file and have a code like

```
restaurant:Restaurant;
getRestaurant(){
this.restaurantService.get(id).subscribe(result=>{
   this.restaurant=result;
   }
 );
}
```

As mentioned in the doc I am expecting when the HTML is first loaded it needs to be populated which works fine. This means my API is called before HTML comes to the browser and the `getRestaurant()` function is processed.

I realized that my `getRestaurant()` function is also called on the client side one more time. That is also okay since I didn't use `isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)` when calling the `getRestaurant()`.

What I am trying to understand is that isn't calling the same API 2 times bad, because I might be doing some heavy operations in backend? I also tried to use `isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)` and didn't make a second call but this time `this.restaurant` is undefined in the client side and I need that restaurant data for other operations like opening the product detail popup. Shouldn't `this.restaurant` be populated in the client side since we already made the call?

Am I thinking wrongly since I am new to this SSR subject?

Answer (score 0):

You can use TransferState [TransferState](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/TransferState) for this. Get the Restaurant data at server side , transfer it to client side. Something like this

```
readonly DATA: StateKey<string> = makeStateKey<string>('DATA');
constructor(private tState: TransferState) {
  if (!isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId))
     getRestaurant(){
       this.restaurantService.get(id).subscribe(result=>{
       this.tState.set(this.DATA, result as any)
      }
    );
  if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId))
    this. restaurant = this.tState.get(this.DATA, "");

  }
}
```

I know this is bad, but I also expected that SSR means everything will be rendered from the backend. But right now this is the way in angular SSR. The code might be incomplete, comment if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into your network console, and saw this call made another time client-side ? Because it shouldn't be the case, if the call client-side is the same as server-side. If you properly configured your SSR app, the following should happen:

> HttpClient responses are cached while running on the server. After
> that this information is serialized and transferred to a browser as a
> part of the initial HTML sent from the server. In a browser,
> HttpClient checks whether it has data in the cache and if so, reuses
> it instead of making a new HTTP request during initial application
> rendering. HttpClient stops using the cache once an application
> becomes stable while running in a browser.

See here: https://angular.io/guide/ssr#caching-data-when-using-httpclient